# APIs required for google sign-in on Android

Tags: android, google-signin, google-plus-signin, android-developer-api, android-googleapiclient

I have been following this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) to add a sign-in button in an android application and retrieve users basic profile information.

How ever, it seems that I have accidentally disabled a required API from the Developers console and now the sign-in that used to work no longer work.

Please could anyone tell me the full list of APIs that needs to be enabled in-order to have a functional sign-in button with GoogleApiClient.

The list of APIs that I have currently enabled are

- Debuglet Controller API
- Google Cloud Logging API
- Google Cloud SQL
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API
- Google+
  API

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry but this APIs would allow google sigin to work but for those who accidentally disable an API, I will leave this on here.

```
Debuglet Controller API
Google Cloud Logging API
Google Cloud SQL
Google Cloud Storage
Google Cloud Storage JSON API
Google+ API
```